# BitBucket Team Multibranch pipeline job is ignoring PRs

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, multibranch-pipeline

I'm using the Bitbucket Branch Source Plugin to automatically configure multibranch pipeline jobs for every repo under a specific project directory within Bitbucket. One repo contains a valid Jenkinsfile. The master branch for that repo builds and deploys fine. However, pull requests for that repo are not being built. I see the following logs:

```
Connecting to <URL> using <credentials>
Looking up repositories of team <Project>
Proposing test-project
Connecting to <URL> using <credentials>
Looking up <Project>/test-project for branches
Checking branch master from <Project>/test-project
Met criteria
Looking up <Project>/test-project for pull requests
Checking PR from ~<user>/test-project and branch feature/thing
Does not meet criteria
```

The specified branch for the pull request does contain a Jenkinsfile, so I do not understand why it says that the criteria are not met. Any suggestions?

The "Automatic branch project triggering" option is set to the default `.*`

I'm using the following plugins to Jenkins:

```
Bitbucket Branch Source Plugin 1.8
Branch API Plugin 1.10.2
GIT Plugin: 2.4.0
Pipeline 2.4
Pipeline: Multibranch 2.8
Pipeline: SCM Step 2.2
SCM API Plugin 1.3
... others omitted for brevity
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I feel dumb.

Jenkins did not have read permission on `<user>'s` fork of the repo containing the branch for the PR.

When you make a PR, all the users with access to the repository receiving the PR are able to view it without issue, so this may be an issue with Bitbucket Server itself (I'm on 4.2.0) not allowing those users to have remote read access to that branch once it has been included in a PR.